# Test grade average python / n.append(float(score)) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, object, input, append, attributeerror

Receiving this error :

```py
n.append(float(score))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'.
```

After running code below:

```py
def averageTestScore(n):
    total = 0
    for x in range(n):
        total += x #sum of numOf tests taken
        avg = total / len(str(n))
        for counter in range(0, n):
            score = float(input("What was your score on test # "))
            # n.append(float(score))
            # score += counter
        return avg

numberOfTests = int(input("How many tests did you take? "))
average = averageTestScore(numberOfTests)
print("The average of those test scores is:", average)
```

Comment: You cast `numberOfTests` as an `int` and pass it to your function as `n`. Then in the commented line you want to append some `score` to `n`. It is not a list, thus the error. Maybe you wanted the score appended to some list that you created in the function? Not really sure what you are trying to achieve: just list the scores in a list or use them to calculate an average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to -

```
def averageTestScore(n):
    score = 0
    for num in range(1,n+1):
       score += float(input(f"What was your score on test {num} "))

    avg = score/n
    return avg

numberOfTests = int(input("How many tests did you take? "))
average = averageTestScore(numberOfTests)
print("The average of those test scores is:", average)
```

Then it should work without error.

You got error, because you cannot append to a integer, only to a list you can append. So, try this different approach. I used `f-strings` so that the test number is also shown.

Answer (score 1):

In your code given above , you were trying to append an integer to another integer (Note `n` is the number of tests you had used as a function parameter, **that's why you got an Error**).

I think what you want is to get average of tests.

So, I think this may help you

```
def averageTestScore(n):
    tt=0
    for i in range(n):
        sc=float(input("What was your score on test : "))
        tt+=sc
    return tt/n
numberOfTests = int(input('How many tests did you take ? '))
average = averageTestScore(numberOfTests)
print("The average of those test scores is :", average)
```